# How to remove packages not installed with Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have updated the packages of my development environment and there are packages listed but not installed.

[image]

For example, I would like to remove Doctrine package but if I use this command:

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer remove vendor/doctrine
```

I've got this message:

[image]

How can I remove this package?

**Edit I:**

I want to explain which were the initial packages installed and what we did.

The initial packages installed were:

[image]

And I wanted to add phpunit package, so I have modified my composer.json with:

```
"require-dev":{
    "phpunit/phpunit": "6.*"
},
```

And save composer.json and execute this command:

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

And the phpunit was installed but appear so many others packages, like:

doctrine, myclabs, phar-io, phpdocumentor, phpspec, sebastian, theseer, webmozart

Are these packages needed to install phpunit? If not, how can I remove it?

**Edit II:**

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-navigation": "^2.8",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Admin\\": "module/Admin/src/",
            "Usuario\\": "module/Usuario/src",
            "Pedido\\": "module/Pedido/src"
        },
        "classmap": ["vendor/Demo/library"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev":{
        "phpunit/phpunit": "6.*"
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "cs-check": "phpcs",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@development-enable"
        ],
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

Comment: Doctrine is almost certainly a dependency of one of your other packages. If you like, you can confirm this by removing `vendor` and doing `composer install`. Chances are it'll come right back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my original post.

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "*"
    }
} then run composer update and  then remove again and run composer update

Comment: Please, read my edit I. I don't want to install doctrine. Thanks.

Comment: @JoséCarlos Your fundamental issue is you need to stop poking around in `vendor`. You shouldn't ever need to poke around in there manually, and anything in it is there because it should be there based on what your `composer.json` says should be there.

Comment: Also, *you* may not require Doctrine (or any other vendor package) that gets installed. However, *it* (being one of the vendors that you *do* require), *could* need that a certain vendor is present. If you were to install my own "address" module, you would also get my "form", "mvc" modules and their requirements (they have their own composer.json files), would would include more vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `composer.json` results in the installation of `doctrine/instantiator` ("A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors"), which is a dependency of `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects`, which is a dependency of `phpunit`.

You haven't installed Doctrine.

Comment: Ok, I understand ... But now, If I try to access to phpunit writing the command I've got the response that "phpunit" doesn't exist and If I want to install use "sudo apt get install phpunit" ... I don't understand anything. Is not enough to isntall phpunit to config in composer.json?

Comment: Installing PHPunit using Composer puts its executable in your application itself at `vendor/bin/phpunit` - just run that instead of `phpunit`. It doesn't install it globally, that'd be what you'd use `apt-get` for, or to do it using Composer you'd want to do a global install: https://akrabat.com/global-installation-of-php-tools-with-composer/